# VPN connection between Endian firewall and Android phones

Tags: vpn, openvpn, ipsec, android, endian-firewall

We have an endian firewall (community, 2.4.0) as gateway, which is already serving as OpenVPN and IPSec endpoint (net-to-net). And we have many Android phones (most of them running Android 2.2 FroYo).

I'm currently trying to set up a VPN connection between the Android phones and the endian firewall. Thus the option would be OpenVPN or IPSec. For Android there is no "official" OpenVPN application. The ones available require root access, custom kernel modules for tun etc. That leaves IPSec as an option, as it's supported by Android.

I tried setting up an IPSec tunnel with PSK for testing on endian, but the phones keeps asking for username and password (PSK is set on the phone), which I don't know how to configure on endian. The only option available on endian is for OpenVPN users. If PSK tunnels work, I want to switch to PKI authentication with certificates, but I can't import the endian root key to Android as it is in PEM-format instead of p12.

How can I get IPSec running on endian firewall and android?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have my Android connected to a SonicWall appliance using IPSec. I have not been asked for user name and password when connecting, but I have to enter a password to protect the PSK. Did you happen to enable the L2TP password on the phone? This option should be left unchecked if you do not have an L2TP enabled firewall.

EDIT
I had a look at the setup on the firewall, and I could see that XAuth was configured for logging in. Not sure if this is supported by edian, but you should check.

Comment: Android only supports PPTP and L2TP VPN connections. Thus there seems to be no option to connect it to endian firewall. (Same is true for iPhones) Currently I'm running a OpenVPN client on the phone, which is a big drawback in battery life. Another option would be to use the PPTP passthrough of endian, but that would make a second server necessary. Nevertheless: your answer is the best one. ;)

Comment: Sorry to hear that it didn't work. If you'd like to switch to a different firewall I can recommend SonicWall which seems to work with Android at least.